# Loop inside loop using multiple variables

Tags: excel, vba

I am having trouble making a program work in Excel.

I need loop through all the lines in my excel spreadsheet, and loop through multiple possible cells for each line.

```
Sub DoubleLoop() 
    Dim i As Long
    Dim Carr As Integer

    For i = 2 To 49235
        For j = 2 To 27
            If Range("P" & i).Value = ("Y" & j) And Range("S" & i).Value = ("Z" & j) And Range("P" & i).Value = ("AA" & j) Then
                Range("P" & i).Value = "Keep"
            ElseIf j < 27 Then
                j = j + 1
            ElseIf j = 27 Then
                Range("X" & i).Value = "Remove"
            End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Whilst editing your question to tidy up your code it became apparent that you appear to be missing `Next j` from your code.  Is that what is causing your error?

Comment: `Next j` is missing.

Comment: Just a tip, if you correctly format and indent your code in future, simple grammatical errors such as missing `Next`s, `End If`s, and other closing statements, become very obvious.

Comment: And once you add the `Next j`, `j = j + 1` will be redundant.

Comment: Thanks for the editing, I'm new to using VBA. If I add in the "Next j" I still get "Remove" on the lines where I should be getting "Keep". Is there something else that is wrong?

Comment: Yes you need to exit the inner loop as soon as you get the positive, otherwise it will only return the result of the Y27 every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the comments.  Use `Next j` and exit the inner loop when criteria is met.

```
Sub DoubleLoop()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim Carr As Integer

    For i = 2 To 49235
        Range("P" & i).Value = "Remove"
        For j = 2 To 27
            If Range("P" & i).Value = ("Y" & j) And Range("S" & i).Value = ("Z" & j) And Range("P" & i).Value = ("AA" & j) Then
                Range("P" & i).Value = "Keep"
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Now that gives me an error at  "Next j". Compile error: Next without For